# Animated matplotlib in an PyQt5 interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I try to make an animated plot in an interface using matplotlib with Python3.

The goal is to have a plot that start animating using a button.
Here is a minimalistic code :

```
import sys, os, random
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class AnimationWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.animate_button = QPushButton("animate", self)
        self.animate_button.clicked.connect(self.on_animate)
        hbox.addWidget(self.animate_button)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 400)
        self.phase = 0.0
        self.y = np.sin(self.x + self.phase)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.plot(self.x, self.y)

    def update(self, i):
        self.phase += np.pi/10.
        y = np.sin(self.x + self.phase)
        self.axes.plot(self.x, y)

    def on_animate(self):
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.update, interval=500)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    aw = AnimationWidget()
    aw.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

When I press the animate button, animate function does nothing. 
In fact, even prints inside update functuon does not work when the button is pressed.

Any idea why it is not working ?

Comment: You need to redraw the canvas after adding the animation to it. `self.figure.canvas.draw_idle()`

Comment: Indeed, that solved the problem, thanks!